# While incorporating html in sapply, getting wierd error

Tags: html, r, shiny

I was trying to incorporate html in sapply but finding some wierd error. Can anyone help me here?

```
inds <- which(data$col1 == "Y")
data$new[inds] <- sapply(data$new[inds], function(x) htmltools::HTML('<span>',x,'</span>','<span style=\'background :green;font-weight:bold; padding: 10px;  padding:1px 5px 1px 5px; color : white\'>R</span>'))
```

> Error in (function (name, val, shinysession)  :
> No handler registered for type .clientdata_output_ I can not come <span style='background :green;font-weight

Comment: No, Can't help (sorry) without some code.

Comment: Please write a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)